# Laggy when play gear VR build

Tags: unity-game-engine, frame-rate, virtual-reality, oculus, gear-vr

I'm creating VR game for Gear VR device. I'm using unity 2019.1.2 version. Even though it showed higher frame rate and lesser draw call amount in my game, when playing its gives slow response. I reduce the materials amount and now only using 2 to 3 materials for whole scene. I tested using Samsung S6. Can't figure it out what's the wrong here.

Many thanks for your considerations

[image: FPS and draw call]
[image: One material for whole game]

Comment: you have like 2 million verts there .. is it possible this is simply a little bit too much? You should try [profiling](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html). Only because it runs fine on your PC doesn't mean it is renderable on your phone or target device

Comment: +1 @derHugo. Also, you can try to profile your app and see the bottlenecks: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerWindow.html

Comment: Do you know any preferred verts count for this kind of scene? and how I can reduce verts count if its the problem? any suggestions much appreciated